# Create download link for music or video

Tags: html, audio, video, browser, href

i have html file with video and audio file. and i want to links file such as mp3 or mp4 using tag a href and download that file. My video and audio file stored in same folder with my html file.

i have tried this code :

```
<a href="music/hermin.mp3" target="_blank">download</a>
```

but not downloaded my file, just open a new tab with a play pause controls in the center.

from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793751/how-can-i-create-download-link-in-html) i get to add "download" to my href tag, but it is for modern browser. How about for old browser?

how i can create a download link for my video/audio in html file and support for all browser (not only for modern browser)?

thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can try this. I've tried it, and it's working for me.

```
<a href="link/to/your/download/file" download> Download link </a>
```

Comment: Almost all browsers support this attribute but note that iOS Safari and IE don't. See this page for the latest support: https://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: thanx bro for help

Comment: Doesn't work on Firefox if file is from another domain.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444250/download-attribute-not-working-in-firefox-but-working-in-chrome

Comment: Doesn't work on Chrome if file is from another domain

Answer (score 10):

It depends of your browser settings and plugins however if you are using php you can do a script to download the file like this one:

```
<?php   
if (isset($_GET['file'])) { 
    $file = $_GET['file'] ;
        if (file_exists($file) && is_readable($file) && preg_match('/\.mp3$/',$file))  { 
            header('Content-type: application/mp3');  
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"");   
            readfile($file); 
        } 
    } else { 
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); 
    echo "<h1>Error 404: File Not Found: <br /><em>$file</em></h1>"; 
} 
?>
```

save it as download.php

then create a link like this one

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="download.php?file=test.mp3">download</a>
</body>    
</html>
```

It should work now, have a nice day.

Comment: Short & sweet code, just the way a noob can understand. +1