# Download attribute not working in Firefox but working in chrome

Tags: javascript, html

This fiddle is not working in firefox but working in chrome.

I have tried using this :

```html
<p>Click on the w3schools logo to download the image:<p>

<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download="aa">
  <img border="0" src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142">
    </a>

<p><b>Note:</b> The download attribute is not supported in IE, Safari or Opera version 12 (and earlier).</p>
```

Link to fiddle : JsFiddle

Comment: No link to the jsFiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fztnwnbL/ - JsFiddle Lnk

Comment: Anyway, what exactly are you asking?

Comment: Don't use absolute urls in your code.

Answer (score 9):

first of all in firefox, you cant mark an a element to download from another domain
so an a like this wont work

```
    <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
```

but this other will work on firefox

```
    <a href="img/book.png" download>
```

Firefox need to be from the same domain, so a relative url, will work fine.

:) goog luck

Comment: note that it should work on remote urls in FF if the server emits CORS headers.

Comment: @dandavis I've added CORS headers, with * for origin, and I can see them coming back to the browser, but it has made no difference.

Comment: Searching around some more, found a confirmation that this is not possible with FF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318017/html5-download-attribute-not-working-when-downloading-from-another-server-even

Comment: I just tested it, and it seems to be broken now in Firefox.