# <a href /> download tag not working on Firefox/Safari for a PDF file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, safari, github-pages

I have a personal website made with ReactJS hosted on github pages.

I have a pdf file located at /docs/resume.pdf

When I try and use:

```
<a href="docs/resume.pdf" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

The browser navigates to https://mydomain.me/docs/resume.pdf but just displays my main ReactJS page.

From googling around, this may be caused by the React router?  I am not a web developer, but I tried to use the download tag as a solution.

However,

```
<a href="docs/resume.pdf" target="_blank" download="resume.pdf">Download</a>
```

only works for Chrome or if I right-click download the link on Firefox/Safari.  If I left click in Firefox/Safari, a download pop-up appears but the file that is downloaded is under 1kb and is corrupted.

When examining the above process in the Firefox dev tools, there is a GET request for my resume.pdf but no response.  I want to reiterate that the process works fine on Chrome and the resume.pdf file is present and accessible on the server.

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this or how to solve it?

Edit: It's not related to using an external link, I'm using a relative link to my file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download attribute not working in Firefox but working in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444250/download-attribute-not-working-in-firefox-but-working-in-chrome)

Comment: Does your server support the pdf content type?

Comment: @nixkuroi The content type is supported by the sever because it works fine with chrome.