# Download mp3 instead of playing

Tags: html, download, mp3

I can't download an mp3 file from any browser. Instead the browser always plays from the new window. I've seen similar questions, but no answer helped.

`<a id="download_${i}" href=${val.ref} download>Download</a>`

I also tried:

`<a id="download_${i}" href=${val.ref} download="test.mp3">Download</a>`

but doesn't work. Is there any simple way to download the mp3 file?

Comment: Is the download served from the same origin?

Comment: I believe so. I'm download my own mp3 files from my db

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956434/create-download-link-for-music-or-video

Comment: I tried the solution from an above link before, but doesn't work for me.