# How to download file using anchor tag <a>

Tags: html

Why is this not working:

**download.html**

```
<a href="jsplogin.jar">download</a>
```

The `jsplogin.jar` file is in the same folder has the `download.html` file.

when I click the download link the file `jsplogin.jar` should download
but its trying to open the file in the browser.
when I right clicked on the link and selected "save link" nothing is happening.

Comment: if you change it to another file, does that work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create download link in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793751/how-can-i-create-download-link-in-html)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

In HTML5, in most browsers you can add a 'download' attribute to the `a` element.

for example:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/index.html" download>Download</a>
```

Based on this question. [How can I create download link in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793751/how-can-i-create-download-link-in-html)

Comment: the download attribute does not work on Safari. And there is no plans for supporting in the future.
http://caniuse.com/#feat=download
Safari is no less than IE is some sense

Comment: This is not working in mozilla firefox. It is redirecting me back to a new tab when i anchor a .jpg file

Comment: @catch22 https://caniuse.com/#feat=download (just tested it in edge and firefox on windows myself and it worked)

it's important to note that this attribute only works for same-origin URLs.

Answer (score 5):

The download attribute didn't work for me, but this did:

`<a href="myfile.csv" target="_blank">Download</a>`

The opens a new tab but downloads the file and closes the tab once it realizes it's not a file type it should render. In my case it was a .csv, I did not test with .jar but i imagine you'd get the same result.

Answer (score 4):

Use the "download" attribute:

```
<a href="jsplogin.jar" download>download</a>
```

Comment: This is not creating a blob automatically. the href link is the link of the file in the backend server. So instead of creating a blob it is displaying it in browser.