# Download attribute in <a> tag doesn't work when file URL called from sub domain

Tags: css, html

I have a blog [here](http://blog.idevelopweb.site/email-newsletters/simple-welcome-newsletter/) where I have used an anchor tag (`<a>`) with the `download` attribute for an HTML file:

```
<a href="http://www.idevelopweb.site/newsletters/welcome-simple/welcome-simple.html" download>Download it here <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of link to download]

Expected: when the user clicks, it should open the dialogue box to download the file.

However, it navigates to the file. AFAIK, it was working earlier. Not sure what happened, or am I missing something? As per this [w3schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp), ".html" file is allowed.

Any help would be much appreciated without using JavaScript.

**EDIT:** 
This blog is in a [subdomain (http://blog.idevelopweb.site/)](http://blog.idevelopweb.site/) and I'm calling the HTML file which is in the [root directory (http://www.idevelopweb.site/)](http://www.idevelopweb.site/) so I have used an absolute path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to download file using anchor tag <a>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607309/how-to-download-file-using-anchor-tag-a)

Comment: Use: <a href="/newsletters/welcome-simple/welcome-simple.html" download="">Download it here <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> so without the http:// etc

Comment: download attribute only works for same-origin URLs.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes

Answer (score 6):

I may direct you to [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).

Your problem is the same origin policy of the download attribute. So either use the same url or relative path.

Comment: does it applicable to sub domain too

Answer (score 1):

Download file when clicking on the link (instead of navigating to the file):

```
<a href="link" download="logo">
```

Note: The download attribute is not supported in Edge version 12, IE, Safari 10 (and earlier), or Opera version 12 (and earlier)

Answer (score 0):

In your Code

```
<a href="http://www.idevelopweb.site/newsletters/welcome-simple/welcome-simple.html" download>Download it here <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

The `href` contain link of the webpage instead of the data , image or file which nedded to be downloaded. The webpage cant be downloaded using download attribute of anchor tag.Thus it should be in format:

```
<a href= "--link of image or file to be downloaded--"  download > Download </a>
```

For example:

```
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download> Download </a>
```

This download the `myw3schoolsimage.jpg` image

Comment: .html file is allowed, we can use it

Comment: I have yet to find a way to "error trap" a download link. Suppose the file no longer exists. Should be a way to get javascript to show an alert