# Download button in react to csv link not working within material-ui table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, react-router, material-ui

I am trying to workout how to include a csv file link to a button within my react material table cell.

From the backend db, I have a column that holds a link to a csv file on a server, i.e.

```
filePath = 'https://my-file-server/files/outcome.csv'
```

that has been assigned to `filePath` within my react component.

I then want to basically emulate a `<a href={filePath}>Download CSV</a>` within my table cell, so tried using React-Router Link, i.e.:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

<TableCell>
  <Link to={filePath}>
    <Button>
      Download CSV
    </Button>                  
  </Link>
</TableCell>
```

Now I am running my app from `localhost:3000/my-route` and when I click on my `Download CSV` button, it actually changes my url path to:

`http://localhost:3000/my-route/my-file-server/files/outcome.csv`

which is not what I want. I actually expected it to point directly to:

`https://my-file-server/files/outcome.csv` and then thought it would just download within my browser to my computer's download directory.

Unsure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `react-router` `Link` components only link to internal paths. If you need to link to an external resource use the regular anchor `<a>` tag. Don't forget to specify the `download` attribute.

Comment: @DrewReese - I actually tried the `<a>` tag but didn't seem to work. Could you pls provide a sample on how to use with `download` attribute.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21608247/8690857 This one was also useful, and includes a link to another SO answer with very in-depth explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/50695407/8690857

Comment: @DrewReese - the first SO thread worked for my requirements. Not sure if you want to answer my question, so that I can accept your solution or your direction to the solution?