# How to realize that clicking <a> tag leads to http request and do not jump to the new page?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a download link.

Here is my HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="../images/icons/word.png" alt="Word"></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="../images/icons/excel.png" alt="Excel"></a>
<a href="/download/test.ppt"><img src="../images/icons/ppt.png" alt="PPT"></a>
<a href="/download/test.pdf"><img src="../images/icons/pdf.png" alt="PDF"></a>
```

When I click `<a>` tag, I want to perform an http request, and the `<a>` tag really does that. But it also jumps to the new page. I do not want that to happen.

I searched and found some solutions such as setting `<a>` tag's `href="#something"`, or use ajax. However, those solutions are not what I want.

**I am wondering there is a better solution for doing this?** *PS: I really do not want to use ajax to realize these in here.*

Comment: No, that make no sense. Anchor tags are used to navigate, you can't just send a request without going anyware using standard behavior. Supressing default behavior (navigation) + ajax is the best you can do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create download link in html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793751/how-can-i-create-download-link-in-html)

Comment: just turn the _href_ into _data-href_, and in the JS code, use _a.dataset.href_ instead of _a.href_ .

Comment: you can also use onclick='return false' , but it's better to cancel the event and preventDefault in your code that binds to the ajax.

Comment: So what *should* happen? What should happen to the HTTP response?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela , you can find my codes in second answers.I hope that is useful for you.

Comment: I wasn’t asking for code. I was asking for a clarification of the question. Currently it falls into the “unclear what you are asking” question. If you need to present code to clarify what is being asked, please do so by editing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the target to a new tab. In chrome this tab closes automatically.

```
<a href="/download/test.ppt" target="_blank"><img src="../images/icons/ppt.png" alt="PPT"></a>
```

Comment: And what happens in Internet Explorer?  Opera?  Safari?  Firefox?

Comment: Depending on the version a new tab or a new window is opened.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/2793756/4592312

Comment: Thanks, i am testing with your way.

Comment: Yes,it works well in IE11,and the latest version of Opera,Firefox,Chrome and Safari in windows platform.

Answer (score 0):

HTML codes are:

```html
<a href="../downloads/test.docx" target="_blank"><img src="../images/icons/ppt.png" alt="PPT"></a>
```

I use nodejs for server,and nodejs codes are:

```
fs.stat(filepath, function(err, stats) {
    if (err)
        throw err;

    var stream = fs.createReadStream(filepath);
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', mime.lookup(filepath));
    response.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;    filename=test.docx');
    response.writeHead(200);
    stream.pipe(response);
});
```