# How can I create download link for mongodb data in HTML?

Tags: html, mongodb

I've seen this question [How can I create download link in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793751/how-can-i-create-download-link-in-html). One solution to create a link for download is using this `<a href="link/to/your/download/file" download="filename">Download link</a>`. However, if the data source is mongodb, what `href` should be set?

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the path of the file where it's available in the database. Let's say your file is http://www.w3schools.com/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg so in the response where you have to return the location you can put

`<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
  [<img border="0" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7CZv.jpg" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142">][1]`

Comment: What if the data source is  my mongodb?