# Attribute download on Safari Browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I was doing a project and I faced an issue with the attribute `download`: I discovered that it isn't supported by **Safari** browser (according to documentation).

Here's a snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded&a" download>Press to Download</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

I searched a way to do it with pure `Javascript` or `Angular`, but I didn't find nothing. Would be great if someone had a solution.

Comment: This has all of the ways: [How can I create download link in html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793751/how-can-i-create-download-link-in-html)

Comment: No, it isn't duplicate. There is no answer to work with Safari browser.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2793756/5743988) or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24694545/5743988) on that post. There isn't a way to do it with JavaScript. It requires editting the response headers.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
<a href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/"
   download="apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded&a">
   Press to Download</a>
```