# Create Download Link Properly

Tags: html

I am new at web developing, I was trying to create download link for a file. This is the code:

```
<a href="http://symphonyrecords.ir/ARTISTS/Sasan-Khan-Namoondi/SasanKhan-Namoondi[320].mp3" target="_blank" download="SasanKhan-Namoondi[320]">           
<button class="downBtn1">Download</button></a>
```

But when I click the link the file starts downloading inside the browsers not in IDM. (I have tested other links from websites and there was no problem). Should I do something in the meta tag or something ?

Comment: Did you check the view source of the functional links. May be that can help you to identify the cause.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: that's weird , everything looks just fine

Comment: Your code in a jsfiddle works just fine for me. https://jsfiddle.net/2xxh0cu8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the server side language you have?

You need to set the below header from the server response,

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=SasanKhan-Namoondi[320].mp3;
```

On the other hand, you can do the same at web server level. For an instance, if you use Apache, you can do this with .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(mp3|MP3)$">
        ForceType audio/mpeg
        Header set Content-Disposition "attachment"
        Allow from all
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Also, you have to enable headers module to make this works,

Make sure the below is checked

> Apache -> Apache Modules -> headers_module

Answer (score 1):

After one day research and strangling i found the answer ... I just add ***onclick*** method and put the file link with **www** inside ***windows.open*** like this  :

```
<a onclick="window.open ('http://www.symphonyrecords.ir/ARTISTS/Sasan-Khan-Namoondi/SasanKhan-Namoondi[320].mp3', ''); return false" href="javascript:void(0);" download>            
 <button class="downBtn1">Download</button></a>
```

This is not the best answer but it will do the job

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://example.com/files/myfile.pdf" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

You can try this link:-[How can I create download link in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793751/how-can-i-create-download-link-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks totally fine so it's certainly something with your browser or the download manager.
Have you tried it with another download manager?

Maybe you can give [this one](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/) a try.