# Downloading web page source code using links

Tags: html

I'd like to quickly download source codes of websites in html, which links are listed on another website.

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post code and effort. At least paste your title into google before asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793751/how-can-i-create-download-link-in-html

Comment: There are these programs called web browsers, I hear they do a pretty good job of downloading web page sources.

Comment: @wroniasty Newfangled stuff… Telnet for president!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily download html of websites copying url on [this website](https://websitedownloader.io/).

Hope I helped you !