# Initiating a download with command line parameters

Tags: javascript, html, exe

This question is a followup to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793751/how-can-i-create-download-link-in-html) question (and I assume several other) about embedding a download link in an HTML page.
I need to create such page which will follow a successful purchase of a software using PayPal. The page contains several "tokens" such as "PayerID" and I wonder if there is a way to initiate a download but adding some command line arguments to it so when the downloaded file is clicked, it will be opened with these arguments.
For example: if the file is "update.exe", and the argument is "Token=1234" it will be opened as "update.exe token=1234".

Comment: To clarify further, the ideal solution would be:

    <iframe width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" src="myprogram.exe arg1 arg2"></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

No.

The closest you could get would be for the server to generate (i.e. compile) a custom executable based on the data in the link.

Comment: @MichaelHaephrati — Too bad. It's still impossible.

Comment: I realize that. Thanks