# Javascript file download with Joomla

Tags: javascript, html, css, joomla

I am coding in Joomla in which I have self synchronized three audio tracks i.e when one of them starts on the web page the other stop and below is the JS code for the same;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function _(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }

    //function Download(url) {


    //document.getElementById('my_iframe').src = url;
    //};

    function audioApp() {
        var audio = new Audio();
        var audio_folder = "/images/audios/how-to-meditate/relaxation/";
        var audio_ext = ".mp3";
        var audio_index = 1;
        var is_playing = false;
        var playingtrack;
        var trackbox = _("trackbox");
        var tracks = {
            "track1": ["Relaxation in the Forest", "relaxation-in-the-forest"],
            "track2": ["Relaxation of the Muscles", "relaxation-of-the-muscles"],
            "track3": ["Relaxation with the Breath", "relaxation-with-the-breath"]
        };
        for (var track in tracks) {
            var tb = document.createElement("div");
            var pb = document.createElement("button");
            //var dn = document.createElement("button");
            var tn = document.createElement("div");
            tb.className = "trackbar";
            pb.className = "playbutton";
            //dn.className = "download";
            tn.className = "trackname";
            tn.innerHTML = tracks[track][0];
            pb.id = tracks[track][1];
            tb.appendChild(pb);
            pb.addEventListener("click", switchTrack);
            tb.appendChild(tn);
            trackbox.appendChild(tb);
            audio_index++;
        }
        audio.addEventListener("ended", function() {
            _(playingtrack).style.background = "url(images/icons/play.JPG)";
            playingtrack = "";
            is_playing = false;
        });

        function switchTrack(event) {
            if (is_playing) {
                if (playingtrack != event.target.id) {
                    is_playing = true;
                    _(playingtrack).style.background = "url(images/icons/play.JPG)";
                    event.target.style.background = "url(images/icons/pause.JPG)";
                    audio.src = audio_folder + event.target.id + audio_ext;
                    audio.play();
                } else {
                    audio.pause();
                    is_playing = false;
                    event.target.style.background = "url(images/icons/play.JPG)";
                }
            } else {
                is_playing = true;
                event.target.style.background = "url(images/icons/pause.JPG)";
                if (playingtrack != event.target.id) {
                    audio.src = audio_folder + event.target.id + audio_ext;
                }
                audio.play();
            }
            playingtrack = event.target.id;
        }
    }
    window.addEventListener("load", audioApp);

</script>
```

Below is the Styling;

```
<style scoped="scoped" type="text/css">
.trackbar {
    background: #FFF;
    height: 50px;
    font-family: "Arial";
}

.trackbar:nth-child(even) {
    background: #FFF;
}


.playbutton {
    opacity: .8;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
    background: url(images/icons/play.JPG) no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}

.playbutton:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.trackname {
    float: left;
    color: #000;
    margin: 12px 400px 0px 14px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

And the html code is;

```
<div id="trackbox">&nbsp;</div>
```

Having achieved this I want to place a download icon besides every mp3 which allows me to download the track, I have the link to download the file and it is placed in the media (Content) of Joomla and also I want a icon to be placed which will trigger the download onClick.
Is there a JS script code available with which I can implement the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create download link in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793751/how-can-i-create-download-link-in-html) if html only is fine, or [Download file using javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery) if actually needing js.

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved the issue;

```
<a href="audiofile.mp3" id="anything" hidden="" download=""></a> <input alt="Submit" src="images/icons/download.jpg" type="image" onclick="document.getElementById('anything').click()" />
```