# force "save file" on download URL

Tags: url, sharepoint, download

I have a template file saved in my Microsoft SharePoint document library, I am using a promoted link tile (linking directly to the file in the SharePoint) to make it easier for users to download it.

Problem is, I don't want people to open the file directly, but to force them to save the file first. Is there any way to do so just by adding something in the URL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML5, most browsers you can add a 'download' attribute to the a element.
for example:
Download

Refer: [How can I create download link in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793751/how-can-i-create-download-link-in-html)

Comment: it seems adding html code in the url does not work in some browser so it won't do, as I need it to work on all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there it. Add "/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceURL=" after the site name.

If the direct URL is sp.contoso.com/SharedDocuments/myfile.docx, then the download URL is sp.contoso.com/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceURL=/SharedDocuments/myfile.docx