# Image in span class as link

Tags: html

This may sound stupid but I am having troubles adding a link to the following code:

```
<span class="image fit"><img src="images/pic.png" alt="pic" /></span>
```

How could I add a link to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create download link in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793751/how-can-i-create-download-link-in-html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

`<span class="image fit"><a href="http://www.mylink.com/"><img src="images/pic.png" alt="pic" /></a></span>`

Comment: Thank you! don't know why I was struggeling with this for so long

Answer (score 0):

Adding a link in html be like :

```
<a href="where you go when you click">the text or img </a>
```

Comment: Could you implement this into my code? that is where I am having troubles with

Answer (score 0):

Try following snippet.

```
<!-- going to google, after clicking -->
<a href="https://www.google.com">
    <span class="image fit"><img src="images/pic.png" alt="pic" /></span>
</a>
```