# Download and open .APK file automatically on Mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, apk

I have a button in my Native App(Cordova) :

```
<li><a href="myapp.apk" download="myapp.apk">Download</a></li>
```

The button download is not working on mobile... And I would like, when download's finished, that the apk file opens automatically.

Comment: Seems like you don't speak English fluently... I improved it a little. ;)

Comment: I'm sure you can "force" a file download... But to open it is another thing.

Comment: @ Louys Patrice Bessette attribute download is not working in mobile ? how i can force it ?   
Thank's

Comment: It is supposed to work the way you have it, so have a look at the path to the file and the filename itself in the `href`. see this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16316830/2159528)

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems like in your path. If you have the apk stored in somewhere in server, you can provide the path of the file. 
For example

```html
<a href="http://www.thegadgettechie.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/hello-1.jpg" download="hello">Download link</a>
```

This will download the image specified in href tag. 
Make sure your url starts with 'http'. If you didn't specify a path which didn't start with http, cordova will look for the file with respect to the root folder (where your index.html is located).

So if you simply specify

```html
 <a href="myApp.apk" download="myApp">Download link</a>
```

This will look for the file myApp.apk inside the root folder of your app. The above code will work if your myApp.apk is indside your www folder.

`www
---- index.html
---- myApp.apk
---- app.js`

So based on the location of the file, you specify path.