# How to download image from an image URL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, download, imageurl

I have trouble downloading an image when clicking on an image link.
I'm prepending `download?image=` before the image url, it is giving the save option but fails to get downloaded.

Here is my code:

```
<a href={`download?image=${data[0].compress_path}`} download={(data[0].file_name).substring(data[0].file_name.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)} type="application/octet-stream" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

**Note**:Without using download?image= it is opening image in new tab.

Comment: What do you mean "failed to get downloaded"? What happens?

Comment: Prep-ending something that does not exist will give you the exact output it gives now. File should be web accessible, also "download" and "href" attributes need quotes. When you open in new page, image should display.

Comment: take a look to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49736214/force-a-download-to-download-image-instead-of-opening-url-link-to-image/49736875)

Answer (score 0):

My problem has been solved.I used File-saver.js library to download images.
Here is the code :

```
<a  href='javascript:void(0)' onClick={()=>{this.download(data[0].compress_path)}} >Download</a>
```

And below is the download function which i have used:

```
    download=(save)=>{
        var FileSaver = require('file-saver');
        var fileName=save.substring(save.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
        FileSaver.saveAs(save, fileName);
    }
```

**Note**:Use
`import { saveAs } from 'file-saver'`to use saveAs.