# Is it possible to make a button download an image hosted from another domain?

Tags: html

so I'm building a site on a service called ClickFunnels and I wanted to create a download button for one of the images we're hosting. Unfortunate the domain of our image assets is different from the domain I'm trying to put this code on. I read somewhere that the domain path of the image must resolve to the same domain that this code is in. Given that I cannot upload the image to same domain, is there a way to make this download button work normally?

```
<!-- Add icon library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- Auto width -->
<center>
  <button class="btn">
    <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
    <a href="otherdomain.com/image.jpg" download="image.jpg">Download</a>
  </button>
</center>
```

Comment: You would need to rewrite your .htaccess on your public_html or images/ folder to allow "hot-linking" if you have access to it.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to any of that as I'm using ClickFunnels...

Comment: @LeweyJimoya Why do you have a link with `<a>` inside a button with `<button>`? It might be confusing for the UI and the browser to have a link and a button reacting somehow to the same mouse click.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force <a download /> to download image instead of opening url link to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49736214/force-a-download-to-download-image-instead-of-opening-url-link-to-image)