# Downloading image files from s3 bucket from client side

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download, bucket

I am building a website where I am uploading wallpapers on s3 bucket and I want users to be able to download those wallpapers from my website on the click of a button.

Earlier I was using simple **anchor tag** and **download** attribute to download the image file but now if I click on he download button my image just opens in full size in new tab.

I am not sure why this is happening and how can I Fix this. I want to be able to download the image on click not open it new tab.

Comment: Seems related: [Force <a download /> to download image instead of opening url link to image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49736214/174777)

Comment: Yeah it does but I cant seem to get a decent solution to it,