# why don't download when i click on on image tag it isnot downloaded

Tags: html, image, hyperlink

i am working on a project in which i have to make a webpage of photographs .  i want to download image in  `a`  tag but when i click in `a` tag it open the image instead downloading . what can  .

```html
<a href="ali.gpj" title="ali"> pleas download image</a>
```

```
</body>
```

Comment: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49736214/force-a-download-to-download-image-instead-of-opening-url-link-to-image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [href image link download on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408146/href-image-link-download-on-click)

Answer (score 0):

when you want to download image or file in link a you should put `download` in `a` tag.

```html
<a href="ali.gpj" title="ali"  download> pleas download image</a>
```

Comment: i wrote this code in vs code but it isn't downloaded