# Download image and don't open the preview - HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to download my immgae with the HTML "download" attribute.
When I click on the image, however, the preview opens and does not download it.
How can I do?

```
<a href="img/qrcode.png" download="qrcode.png">
   <img src="img/qrcode.png" width="300" height="300">
</a>
```

If I leave the URL blank it downloads it, but when I go to open the photo from the downloads it gives me that it is a damaged file

Comment: I just tested that code and, when I clicked on the image, the image was downloaded. I can't reproduce the problem. (Maybe you are dealing with a `file:` scheme URL where cross-origin files prevent the download attribute from working, but it would be pointless to download something from the local file system so that seems unlikely)

Comment: @Quentin If I leave the URL blank it downloads it, but when I go to open the photo from the downloads it gives me that it is a damaged file

Comment: It seems like this may be an issue with your device or browser, not your code. You've written everything in the correct form, so this issue of a preview popping up must be browser-related? Also, when you leave the URL blank and successfully download the file, does adding ".png" to the end of the filename make the file openable?  On certain devices/OS, it's necessary to include the file extension.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force <a download /> to download image instead of opening url link to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49736214/force-a-download-to-download-image-instead-of-opening-url-link-to-image)

Answer (score -1):

The download attribute does not need any value, as it is in W3school:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

unless you want to change the name:

`<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download="w3logo">`

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the question at all.