# Any way to make anchor tag download work on built in PHP dev server?

Tags: php, html, download

According to [chrome download attribute not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872902/chrome-download-attribute-not-working), this html doesn't seem to work on `built in php dev server`:

```
<a href="https://www.python.org/static/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png" download>click me</a>
```

instead of downloading the image or opening the download dialog box, it opens the image in the browser window and that's it. Does this really not work because I'm using `php dev server`? Any way to make it work? I'm using `chrome` to test.

Comment: You could send the link to your server then have PHP retrieve the data and serve it to the client.... Assuming this is a PHP question and looking for PHP answer. Kinda reads like you're looking for the `download` attribute usage though, so an HTML question.

Comment: It looks like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49736214/force-a-download-to-download-image-instead-of-opening-url-link-to-image) might be relevant here. You are running this on a local/dev server, but the download link you are serving is on a different domain. Firefox and Chrome supposedly only support same-origin download links, which this link would not be.

Comment: That download is 100% a client issue and has nothing to do with PHP or PHP's built in server. PHP, or your server, has nothing to do with a user clicking on a link to some third-party site in the front end, download or not.

Comment: How is which server you're using relevant? Isn't that a thing between your browser and the server behind that link? Does it work when you're not using php dev server?

Comment: @brombeer It is outlined in that post/answer. Same-origin download links are a browser security policy. If the download link is on a different domain, it is up to the other domain/server whether or not the file is served as a download or not. So if python.org does not send download headers with that file, it will not be automatically downloaded. You can't control how another server's content is served.

Comment: @EssXTee - That still has nothing to do with PHP's built in server. That issue would be the same regardless which web server they're using since their web server isn't involved in that request at all.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the question you linked to: [Chrome Download Attribute not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872902/chrome-download-attribute-not-working). The answer is already there at https://stackoverflow.com/a/35290284/5947043 - the `download` attribute only works for same-origin URLs. You're linking to an off-site URL. So then it's up to the remote server whether to set headers (in the response which returns the image) which suggest to the browser that it should download it directly, and then it's up to your browser whether it takes any notice of those headers or not.

Comment: @M.Eriksson The download/content he is serving isn't coming from PHP's built in server. So why would his built in server control the content from python.org? The built in PHP server may be running the page with the link, but the content is being served by a different server, which has control of the `Content-Disposition` HTTP header. This is what controls the browsers default download behavior.

Comment: @EssXTee Thanks, I though of something like that. I was only asking because OP mentioned "_Does this really not work because I'm using php dev server?_" - which isn't relevant (unless php dev server strips out the download attribute for some reason)

Comment: See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download, to get it from the horse's mouth.