# in django dynamic view how to create a download link and assign a file to the download link in run time

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

***view.py the file  which process the POST request.***

This app takes one excel sheet and xml file are argument , the xml contains some meta about the excel cell location. File its create a xml file in the current directory .  I want to assign this file reference to a anchor tag download link in template.  Hopefully this explain the problem.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import openpyxl
import xmltodict
import collections

def deep_convert_dict(layer):
    to_ret = layer
    if isinstance(layer, collections.OrderedDict):
        to_ret = dict(layer)

    try:
        for key, value in to_ret.items():
            to_ret[key] = deep_convert_dict(value)
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    return to_ret
def index(request):
    if "GET" == request.method:
        return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {})
    else:
        excel_file = request.FILES["excel_file"]
        xml_file = request.FILES["xml_file"]
        #print(xml_file)
        print(excel_file)


        # you may put validations here to check extension or file size

        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file,data_only=True)

        # getting all sheets
        sheets = wb.sheetnames
        print(sheets)

        # getting a particular sheet
        sheet = wb["Paydoc"]
        file1 = open('reelset.xml','a')
        doc = {}
        doc = xmltodict.parse(xml_file.read())
        dict_1 =deep_convert_dict(doc)
        print(dict_1)

        for key, value in dict_1.items() :
            for key1, value1 in value.items() :
                x =  '\n<'+key1+'>\n'
                file1.write(x)
                for key2, value2 in value1.items() :
                    print (key2)
                    reel1 ='\t<Reel ReelIndex="'+key2[-1]+'">'+'\n\t\t'+'<Elements>'+'\n'
                    coloumn = value2['Coloumn']
                    startrow = int (value2['StartIndex'][1:-1])
                    endrow = int (value2['StopIndex'][1:-1])
                    count1 = 0
                    while(startrow < endrow):
                        c = sheet[coloumn[1:-1]+str(startrow)]
                        strx = '\t\t\t'+'<Element id='
                        strx = strx + '"'+str(count1)+'">'+str(c.value).upper()+'</Element>'+ '\n'
                        reel1 = reel1 + strx
                        strx = ''
                        startrow = startrow + 1
                        count1 = count1 + 1
                    reel1 = reel1 + '\t\t</Elements>'+'\n'+ '\t</Reel>\n'
                    print(reel1)
                    file1.write(reel1)
                    reel1 = ''
                y = '</'+key1+'>'
                file1.write(y)
        file1.close()
        import os
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        print(cwd)
        file2 = open('./reelset.xml','r')
        data = file2.read()
        file2.close()
        return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {"posts":data})

HTML template:

<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            REELSET CREATION WEB TOOL
        </title>
    </head>
    <body style="margin-top: 30px;margin-left: 30px;">
        <form action="{% url "myapp:index" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p>PLEASE UPLOAD MATH EXCEL SHEET</p>

            <input type="file"
                   title="Upload excel file"
                   name="excel_file"
                   style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;"
                   required="required">

                   <p></p>

                    <p>PLEASE UPLOAD REELSET XML CONFIGURATION META DATA</p>
                   <input type="file"
                          title="Upload xml file"
                          name="xml_file"
                          style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;"
                          required="required">
            <p>
            <input type="submit"
                   value="Upload"
                   style="border: 1px solid green; padding:5px; border-radius: 2px; cursor: pointer;">

        </form>

        <p></p>
        <hr>

        {% for row in excel_data %}
            {% for cell in row %}
                {{ cell }}&nbsp;&nbsp;
            {% endfor %}
            <br>
        {% endfor %}

        {{posts|escape }}




    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create download link in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793751/how-can-i-create-download-link-in-html)

Comment: Where's your code? Please take a look at [ask] to familiarise yourself with some of the principles of StackOverflow.

Comment: This is my first ever post for help in stack overflow. May be not sure how to ask . I am just asking I have created a xml file after some  computation.  I just want  provide a down load link to xml file I have created. I am out of work today will post the code tomorrow.