# Node - file downloaded not prompting using and being saved in project directory

Tags: node.js

When I download a file, it gets downloaded to my project directory and not my downloads folder. There is also no prompt when clicking the download so it also doesn't get downloaded to the users machine, just the server's folder

**router**

```
router.get('/download', function(req, res) {
  getFile(req, res);
  res.redirect('/');
});


function getFile(req,res) {

var file = fs.createWriteStream("file.jpg");
var request = http.get("http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/J---aiyznGQ/mqdefault.jpg", function(response) {
  response.pipe(file);
});


}
```

HTML

```
<form method="get" action="/download">
  <button type="submit">download</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you mean the webpage?  Where is your HTML?

Comment: its just a form with a get method

Comment: What browser?  If this is Chrome, have you set the download action for files?  It would be in `chrome://settings/`.

Comment: it happens with every browser I use

Comment: the nodejs fs ONLY works on the server. You have to send the content of the file in the res. Also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793751/how-can-i-create-download-link-in-html to see how to inform your browser of what is happening (<a download....).