# JS - Change href and trigger image download when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, http, download

I'm trying to download an image using the `download` attribute on an `<a>` tag. Its `href` value is updated when it is clicked.

```js
function Download_Image(element) {
  var mydiv = $("#imageDiv");
  var Image = mydiv[0].children;
  
  mydiv.download = Image[0].src;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="imageDiv">
  <img
    width="200"
    height="140"
    src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-pjQRansD-ig/XAUEH2oe8tI/AAAAAAAAHwE/BgZOyaGnQLYhH2Zjxx86BRvyOs8o9yGjgCLcBGAs/s200/16e3d864-8fb8-4f43-b91e-cc97a75c602f.jpg" />
</div>

<a href="#" onclick="Download_Image(this)" download>Click here to download image</a>
```

However, when I click the link, it downloads the whole HTML page instead of the image.

Comment: Because `.download` should be for `<a>` element, and not for `<div>`. Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23013574/1346234

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create download link in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793751/how-can-i-create-download-link-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `href` attribute of the `<a>` element, not the `download` attribute of the `<div>`.

Anyway, the `download` attribute [is not supported in all browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=download) and might not work in some others if the `Content-Disposition: attachment` header is not set.

For example, if we use an image from Instagram with the following code, it will only work if you append `?dl=1` at the end of the URL:

```js
const links = document.getElementById('links');
const image = document.getElementById('image');

links.onclick = (e) => {
  const link = e.target;
  
  if (link.tagName !== 'A') {
    return;
  }
    
  link.href = `${ image.src }${ link.innerText.includes('WITHOUT') ? '' : '?dl=1' }`;
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#image {
  margin: 8px;
  height: calc(100vh - 16px);
}

#links {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#links > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 14px;
  margin: 4px 0;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#links > a:hover {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="https://scontent-mad1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/e96d73e7938825335c235baedb51e91a/5CAAC2D4/t51.2885-15/e35/46060357_1380937935382732_6380498939567322752_n.jpg" />

<div id="links">
  <a href="#" download> WITHOUT HEADER</a>
  <a href="#" download> WITH HEADER</a>
</div>
```

You could take a look at a library called [`download.js`](http://danml.com/download.html).