# React JS file upload into local memory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-handling

How can i upload a file and save the uploaded file in my computer.

I have references about how to upload into database. But how to store those files into local computer.

Comment: tag is wrong, it is not React specified.

Comment: @Kornflexx Though i agree some more specific tags should be added, I don't think the react tag is wrong here. Most JS tasks are approached differently in React. There's no reason to think that's not the case here.

Comment: i just want to upload a file from front end, and that uploaded file to be store in my computer, can i find a way fot it.

Comment: @Jayakar updated answer to deal with all the possible use-cases I could think of.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using HTML5/Javascript to generate and save a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file)

Comment: @ManavM React is a view library, not a framework. Uploading and saving file is not a view issue.

Comment: By that logic react-router shouldn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The question is how you want to do it..If you want it stored in your filesystem then the only way is to create a link/prompt the user to download it.

Creating a download prompt is detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file).

Creating a link is easily done using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793751/how-can-i-create-download-link-in-html/16316830#16316830).

However if you want to do it programmatically (that is, using JS to automatically create a persistent data store), then it is not typically allowed by browsers as they don't have  access to your file system.

In this case you might want to use something like [IndexedDB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) for this.

If you just want to store some data locally, you can also experiment with the [WebStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)

Comment: You can save any file from a browser as long the server let you download it

Comment: But that's not done programmatically. It's done by prompting the user for it. Or by creating a link for it. Which is not what the OP asked...I think

Comment: Thanks @ManavM, I didn't know that the browsers don't have access to your file system.

Comment: It's a security issue...if websites were able to directly access your file system like that, it would make it incredibly easy to hack into your system.

Comment: You can prompt programmatically a `save as..` UI and this is the standard behavior when you want to store a file. Nothing new.

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini yes which is why I mentioned it in the answer...did you have point?

Comment: You mentioned it after the comment, I was just replying to your comment.