# Firebase download url in <a> opens csv file in browser

Tags: html, angularjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I use Firebase to generate a download link in AngularJS as follows:

```
self.getDownloadUrl = function(storage_ref) {
            var q = $q.defer();
            var storage = firebase.storage();
            storage.ref(storage_ref).getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
              q.resolve(url);
            }).catch(function(error) {
              q.reject(error);
            });
            return q.promise;
        };
```

Then I bind the `url` to an object `scope.downloadUrl`. In my DOM I then try to download the file as follows:

```
<a href="{{scope.downloadUrl}}" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

However, when I click on this link, it opens my .csv file in the browser (looks like a text file with comma separated, tested it on Chrome and Edge). How can I prevent this and just enforce a proper download?

Comment: .csv is already in there. At the end it has the ?session token from firebase

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793751/how-can-i-create-download-link-in-html/16316830#16316830

Comment: Not relevant, I think its something with the Firebase Download Url. Tried that and it didnt work your link