# How to download an fillable pdf on button click event

Tags: javascript, html

I need to save the fillable pdf after the user is done filling it. I basically need a JavaScript function for it. I googled it but didn't found any solution.

```
<embed id="pdf" src="panel.pdf#navpanes=0&scrollbars=0" type="application/pdf"/>
```

Any suggestions is most welcomed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create download link in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793751/how-can-i-create-download-link-in-html)

Comment: No. It will download only a pdf from the source but I want to save the pdf once the user is done editing it.

Comment: You're right. How you generate this PDF?

Comment: This is a simple pdf which I have embedded it in html where user can edit it as well.

Comment: Interesting. Well actually, I'm not familiar with that area but from a short test I made (created the PDF using https://www.jotform.com/) you can submit the form only with acrobat reader and hit on the "download" button just download the original pdf. So I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: Submit the form with acrobat reader? Will the edited pdf will be saved or the original one.

Comment: You can submit the **data** using acorbat reader, not the whole PDF. From a quick search (again, I'm not familiar with that area) I couldn't find a native way - without libraries, to do this. If you want to invest some time, you can a form in html and then put its values in the PDF. Like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHTrsUtmQTo