# Not able to download file using <a> tag

Tags: html

I'm running the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>NHS Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static',filename='css/main.css')}}" />
</head>

<body>
    <a href="nhsgame(Mac).app" download="NHS Game"><img src="https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/901-9019597_apple-logo-riot-chat-logo.png" alt="MacOS" width="120" /></a>
    <a href="nhsgame (Mac).zip" download="NHS Game"><img src="https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/901-9019597_apple-logo-riot-chat-logo.png" alt="MacOS" width="120" /></a>
</body>

</html>
```

the website is loading fine, but when I download the file, it shows it as a '.html' file and underneath it says No file:
[image]

Please help...

Comment: Is there a file with `nhsgame(Mac).app` this name in your root folder with the html.

Comment: Yes, I have put it in the same folder I put the html file, though it is different from the one with the css file. Also, I'm running the HTML file through some python code, which is outside of the folder in which the html file is in. Sorry I failed to mention this in the main post

Comment: are your filenames "nhsgame(Mac).app" and "nhsgame (Mac).zip" ? and are they located in the same folder with the html? share your folder structure if possible

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58125964/11171286

Answer (score -2):

In HTML5, in most browsers, you can add a 'download' attribute to the a element.

for example:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/index.html" download>Download</a>
```

Comment: He is using it. Look before posting!

Comment: He should provide the full URL.

Comment: I'm trying to download a file, not a webpage, and the file's in my local system, so there's no point in providing the 'full link'

Comment: But at the same time, if there is a way to convert a file into a link, that could be useful....