# How to trigger a download of an audio link using JS, without having the browser navigate to a new page?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, browser, download

I want to write a script that downloads some audio files from a web page. Problem is, that simulating the "click" via element.click() doesn't work well, because the browser simply navigates to the URL of that anchor element.
For example:

```
<a href="https://www.somesite.com/someAudioFile.mp3"></a>

const link = document.querySelector('a');

link.click();//Navigates to the url...
```

What I need, is to be able to collect all those links that I need, and simply trigger the download, **without the save-as dialogue appearing**

Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create download link in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793751/how-can-i-create-download-link-in-html) (the second answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add download attribute to  element, without javascript

```
<a href="https://www.somesite.com/someAudioFile.mp3" download></a>
```

Or download with custom name

```
<a href="https://www.somesite.com/someAudioFile.mp3" download="music"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
link.addEventListener('click', (e) => e.preventDefault());
```

Comment: Please explain your answer to be more useful.