# How to get the redirected URL using Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect

I've a url from twilio on a react app, which I'm meant to download it's file content. But the url redirects to the actual URL which contains the file. I'd like to know if their's a way to go about it, since I had used fetch method but it's returning a CORS error message.

Note, audioSource.source contains the URL of the file.

```
fetch(audioSource.source, {
          mode: "no-cors",
          credentials: "include",
          method: "GET",
          // headers: headers,
        }).then(function (response) {
          console.log(audioSource.source);
          console.log(response.url);
        });
```

Comment: if you can create a fake <a> link with `display: none;`, then maybe a `download=""` attribute can be useful like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2793756/17716837 and trigger a `.click()` and if clicked then deleted the <a> tag.... but maybe isn't what you want

Comment: Apparently, I'm using the jszip-utils module getBinaryContent's method to fetch the data based on the URL, so I'm looking for a way to get the final URL just before I get the binary content.