# Download just displays in another tab

Tags: c#

**Front:**

```
<button type="button"
   <a href="http://localhost:5000/export/2fdf8621-03f6-ed11-9609-f8da0c8462f0" id="export" download>
     Gerar QRCode
   </a>
</button>
```

**Back:**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Export/{id}")]
public FileResult Export([FromRoute] string id)
{
    try
    {
        QRCodeGenerator QrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
        QRCodeData QrCodeInfo = QrGenerator.CreateQrCode("MY_URL", QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
        QRCode QrCode = new QRCode(QrCodeInfo);
        Bitmap QrBitmap = QrCode.GetGraphic(60);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        QrBitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
        QrBitmap.Dispose();

        return File(ms.ToArray(), "image/png");
}
```

I try so many thigs... Not work

Comment: What do you want it to do, download the QR Code as an image file to the user's file system?

Comment: Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/16316830/1043380, I'd expect that to work. Try changing your `href` to be relative instead of absolute (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793751/how-can-i-create-download-link-in-html#comment109902616_16316830)

Answer (score 1):

Pass a filename to the File method. This will send information to the browser that makes the browser download the file instead of showing it.

```
return File(ms.ToArray(), "image/png", "QRCode.png");
```