# Javascript file download in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have tried download file using jQuery like this :

```
window.location.href = "docs/eaResponseEsomar-28.docx";
```

it is working in chrome but not in firefox.
I google it but didnt find satisfing answer. how to pragmatically give download link that will work in every browser?
what should be done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21088526/1524085

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force fully download txt file on link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21088376/how-to-force-fully-download-txt-file-on-link)

Comment: i want to do it using jquery.