# How to save a text as .txt file via a downloadable link?

Tags: html, hyperlink, download, streamlit

**HTML newbie here**

I am working on an app using [Streamlit](https://www.streamlit.io/). Based on the user inputs to the fields available, I am generating some data which I want to download in the form of a `.txt` file.

The data that I want to download is generated when I do

```
to_save = abc.serialize().encode("ascii", "ignore")
```

and when I do `print(to_save)`, I get (this is just a small part of a very huge text data)

> b"UNA:+.?
>   'UNB+UNOC:3+9978715000006:14+9978715000006:14+200529:1139+50582307060_WP?+_200101_200201++TL'UNH+1+MSCONS:D:04B:UN:2.3'BGM+7+50582307060_WP?+_200101_200201-1+9'DTM+137:202005291139:203'RFF+Z13:13008'NAD+MS+9978715000006::9'CTA+IC+:Michael
>   Jordan'COM+m.jordan@energycortex.com:EM'NAD+MR+9978715000006::9'"

Now, I want to save this information as a `.txt` file via an HTML link. I am following:

1. [How to download a file in Streamlit](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/how-to-download-file-in-streamlit/1806/12)
2. [How to force fully download txt file on link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21088376/how-to-force-fully-download-txt-file-on-link)

and I have

```
reference = 50582307060_WP+_200101_200201
to_save = abc.serialize().encode("ascii", "ignore")
href = f'<a href="data:text/plain;charset=UTF-8,{to_save}" download={reference}.txt>Download File</a> (right-click and save as {reference}.txt)'
st.markdown(href, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

But this doesn't work and shows as follows:

**The start**

[image]

**The end**

[image]

and when I do:

```
to_save = abc.serialize().encode("ascii", "ignore")
href = f'<a href="data:text/plain;charset=UTF-8" download={reference}.txt>Download File</a> (right-click and save as {reference}.txt)'
st.markdown(href, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

I get

[image]

The problem with this being that the information that has to be saved as a `.txt` file (`to_save = abc.serialize().encode("ascii", "ignore")`) isn't being saved and I get a `Failed-Network error`

What is the mistake that I am doing and how can I enable saving the information stored in `to_save` (`to_save = abc.serialize().encode("ascii", "ignore")`) as an HTML downloadable link? Also, the file should be saved as 'reference.txt', with reference being defined as a variable above.

Comment: Just for debug purposes: does it work when you omit the `download=` attribute and value from the `<a>` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reckon I have found a solution to your problem. Though I can't be entirely sure, it has two causes. The first one lies in the `href` attribute of the download link. The problem here is the `"` (double quotes) in the `to_save` variables data. The html, for what I could test with the by you provided data, renders it as follows:

```html
<a href="data:text/plain;charset=UTF-8,b"UNA:+.? 'UNB+UNOC:3+9978715000006:14+9978715000006:14+200529:1139+50582307060_WP?+_200101_200201++TL'UNH+1+MSCONS:D:04B:UN:2.3'BGM+7+50582307060_WP?+_200101_200201-1+9'DTM+137:202005291139:203'RFF+Z13:13008'NAD+MS+9978715000006::9'CTA+IC+:Michael Jordan'COM+m.jordan@energycortex.com:EM'NAD+MR+9978715000006::9'"" download=filename.txt>Download File</a>
```

As you can see the value of the `href` attribute isn't all in the blue color (here in the stackoverflow code container above). That is because of the `"` that interrupt the string, it closes the earlier opened `"` after `href="`. In order to prevent this behaviour, you should replace the `"` in `to_save` with `&quot;`. To the user this will look the same as `"` but the browser will treat it like a normal string.

You should add the following line of code to your python script to make that happen

```py
to_save = abc.serialize().encode("ascii", "ignore")
#add this line:
to_save = to_save.replace('"','&quot;')
```

Next the `download` attribute doesn't have any double quotes around it's value. It should, formally, look like this: `download="filename.txt". Then again, for safety replace any possible`"`with`"`.

The full python code should now look like this:

```py
reference = 50582307060_WP+_200101_200201
reference = reference.replace('"','&quot;')

to_save = abc.serialize().encode("ascii", "ignore")
to_save = to_save.replace('"','&quot;')

href = f'<a href="data:text/plain;charset=UTF-8,{to_save}" download="{reference}.txt">Download File</a> (right-click and save as {reference}.txt)'
st.markdown(href, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

Hope this helps! If not, please comment.

Comment: Hey @Chiel, thanks for your help. I'll check it tomorrow at work and update you about it.