# pdf download button not working in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have got an ebooks table in the database where path of pdf is defined.What I want is, when a user clicks on the download button, pdf get download.But the download button is not working and I'm also not getting any error from Php.Please help! Thank you.

Code:

```
<div id="data">
        <?php 
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

                        $title  = $_POST['title'];
                        $name  = $_POST['name'];
                        $count = 1;

                        $query = "SELECT * FROM ebooks WHERE $title LIKE '%".$name."%'";
                        $display =  $obj->run_query($query);
        ?>

        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr align="center">
                        <td>No.</td>
                        <td>Title</td>
                        <td>Author</td>
                        <td>Publication</td>
                        <td>Status</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php

                        foreach ($display as $key) { ?>

                    <tr align="center">
                        <td><?php echo $count++;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $key['ebook_title'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $key['ebook_author'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $key['ebook_publication'];?></td>
                        <td><a style="color:white;" href="/admin/ebooks/<?php echo $key['ebook_url'];?>" class="btn btn-round btn-primary">Download</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add download before ending of anchor tag try this :

```
<a style="color:white;" href="/admin/ebooks/<?php echo $key['ebook_url'];?>" class="btn btn-round btn-primary" download>Download</a>
```

Comment: Check if URL of download button is what it has to be, this should work.

Comment: Yeah URL is also the same where this ebook resides @Marko Kunic

Comment: Does it open your pdf in browser ? or just nothing

Comment: No nothing happens when I click on button @Marko kunic

Comment: Then again, your url is not good, it should at least open the pdf in your browser, take value from href and try to open it without button and you can check this maybe `http://stackoverflow.com/a/925867/5258172` but the url is problem.

Comment: try with absolute path

Comment: Yeah, I've also tried that. It's opening when I give this path directly to browser but no luck with this  button ..... @Marko Kunic

Comment: Just tested download of .pdf with relative path, just added download to end of anchor and it is working.

Comment: `<a href="assets/test.pdf" download>Download</a>` I just added pdf to folder and it downloaded it.

Comment: ok.Don't know why it's not working with my <a> tag :/ @Marko Kunic

Comment: You can alternatively use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/364950/926943 - that's a full-proof way and will work for all browsers. :-)

Comment: Can you show me how to embed this code in my Html, please? @HimelNagRana

Comment: I've changed it like this:
<td><a style="color:white;" href="pdf_server?file=<?php echo $key['ebook_url'];?>" class="btn btn-round btn-primary" download>Download</a></td>
but still nothing happened! @HimelNagRana

Comment: @AishaSalman, In the HREF section of your anchor link you have used "pdf_server?". Are you using any framework? If not - you have to specify a server side script there. The most important part is: 
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");            
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
The headers actually directs the browser on what to do. I hope this may help.
Thanks.